# "Trust anchor for certification path not found" on request settings and proguard

Tags: android, proguard, crashlytics

When I set the minifyEnabled option of proguard to true the application can not receive settings with

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

for crashlytics though other networking seem to work fine.

Using retrofit and okhttp for network requests
proguard rules concerning the libraries engaged:

```
-keep class io.fabric.** { *;}
-keep class com.android.okhttp.** { *;}
-keep class com.android.org.conscrypt.** { *;}
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.* { *;}
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp3.**
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp3.* { *;}
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit.http.* <methods>;
}
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
-dontwarn retrofit.**
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and solved it putting the .cer file in release/assets folder...